# Obtaining backtrace with symbols after SIGSEGV from gfortran application

Tags: gcc, gdb, gfortran

I'm compiling with gfortran 4.8.1 with the flags `-ggdb -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wtabs -Wsurprising -fbacktrace -fimplicit-none -fcheck=all -std=f2008`.  Running in gdb I get a backtrace with no procedure names:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000100000000 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffffffd760 in ?? ()
#3  0x3f1a36e2eb1c432d in ?? ()
#4  0x3da5fd7fe1796495 in ?? ()
#5  0x4024000000000000 in ?? ()
#6  0x3eb0c6f7a0b5ed8d in ?? ()
#7  0x408f400000000000 in ?? ()
#8  0x408f400000000000 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

After executing `./gyre`, which segfaults, I invoke `gdb ./gyre core`.  I see a warning `Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error`, but I'm not sure if that's relevant to the problem.

What do I need to do to see where the SIGSEGV occurred?

Update:
So I suspect the stack corruption must be related to a procedure point initialisation, since my code was not segfaulting prior to this change.  I'm not able to provide the full source code, but the relevant snippet is

```
pure function new_default_sim_spec() result(spec)
    type(sim_spec_type)  :: spec

    spec = new_sim_spec(1.0_dp)
end function new_default_sim_spec

pure function new_sim_spec(max_days) result(spec)
    type(sim_spec_type)  :: spec
    real(dp), intent(in) :: max_days

    ! snipped other attribute assignments
    spec%increment_h => increment_h_euler
end function new_sim_spec

abstract interface
    pure function increment_h_iface(spec, state_minus_1) result(state)
        import                              :: sim_state_type, sim_spec_type
        type(sim_state_type)                :: state

        class(sim_spec_type), intent(in)    :: spec
        type(sim_state_type), intent(in)    :: state_minus_1
    end function increment_h_iface
end interface

type sim_spec_type
    ! snipped other attribute declarations
    procedure(increment_h_iface), pointer   :: increment_h => null()
end type sim_spec_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Running in gdb I get a backtrace with no procedure names:

*How* did you run GDB?

I am guessing you did `gdb /path/to/core`. Try `gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core` instead.

Update:

`gdb ./gyre core`. I see a warning ...

That warning is irrelevant (and frequently there, though I don't understand the exact conditions which trigger it).

The *other* obvious way to check where `SIGSEGV` occurred is to simply run the binary under GDB from the start. You don't need to wait for `core`, a simple:

```
gdb ./gyre
(gdb) run
```

should suffice.

Update 2:

> I've tried running the program itself under gdb and have the same problem.
>   I see plenty of expected function names listed by nm so the binary cannot have been stripped.

This implies either:

- some kind of non-standard setting in `~/.gdbinit`, or
- a bug in GDB.

To eliminate the former, try `gdb -nx ./gyre`.

For the latter, try a different version of GDB, or make the binary available somewhere and I can take a look.

**Update 3:**

The reason GDB can't produce a stack trace is that your stack is getting corrupted on line `simulation.f90:45`:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  simulation::new_default_sim_spec () at simulation.f90:45
#1  0x0000000000401054 in gyre () at gyre.f90:21
#2  0x0000000000401fad in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffeb24) at gyre.f90:3
#3  0x00007ffff742876d in __libc_start_main (main=0x401f79 <main>, argc=1, ubp_av=0x7fffffffe878, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe868) at libc-start.c:226
#4  0x0000000000400be9 in _start ()

(gdb) n
41  in simulation.f90

(gdb) bt
#0  simulation::new_default_sim_spec () at simulation.f90:41
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Notice how before line 45 the stack is good, but after it's not. The particular instruction that "wipes" the stack is this one:

```
=> 0x408fde <__simulation_MOD_new_default_sim_spec+93>: movq   $0x0,0x8(%rbp)
```

Without access to your sources, and with 20 years since I last touched Fortran, I can't make an intelligent guess at what kind of Fortran code could provoke such a bug.

Comment: This hasn't helped, I still see `??` where the procedure names should be.  Could it be that the binary missing the symbol table?

Comment: @hertzsprung You binary *could* be missing symbol table, but that would be inconsistent with the command flags you gave for building it. There is no need to guess, just run `nm /path/to/exe`. If you see lots of functions that you expect to see, then your binary is *not* stripped.

Comment: I've tried running the program itself under gdb and have the same problem.  I see plenty of expected function names listed by `nm` so the binary cannot have been stripped.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  No `~/.gdbinit` file exists and `gdb -nx ./gyre` makes no difference that I can tell.  I've uploaded the binary at http://datumedge.co.uk/misc/gyre

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I've attached some of the relevant source code in case you (or someone else) can spot my mistake.

Comment: @hertzsprung It appears to me that your "why doesn't GDB show stack trace" question has been answered, and you have a new "why does this Fortran program corrupt stack" question. It might be best to ask that as a separate question, tagging it with appropriate tags, and supplying *complete* repro case (which should be relatively easy -- the program doesn't have to crash, you just need to show via GDB that the stack is corrupted at some point).

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  I'll award you the bounty when the timer expires.

Answer (score 0):

Newer gcc versions default to dwarf-4 format debug info.  If you have an older toolchain it might not understand it.  Try -gdwarf-2.

Comment: For an un-stripped binary, GDB does not need *any* debug info to show function names in stack trace -- symbol table is enough. Thus this answer is unlikely to be correct.